# Idiomatic way to implement containsAny for Scala SeqLike

Tags: scala

Scala's `SeqLike` implement a method `contains`. How can I cleanly implement a `containsAny` feature?

Let's say I want to find out if a string `string` contains any of the blacklisted characters in `blacklist`:

```
val blacklist = List("(", ")", "[", "]", "{", "}", "<", ">")
string containsAny blacklist
```

How is the best way to implement the second line cleanly?

My version so far looks like this:

```
(blacklist.view map string.contains) contains true
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your best bet is to make the blacklist a set.

```
val blacklist = "()[]{}<>".toSet
```

Now you can use `exists` to find if any of those characters exist in your string.  Since `Set[T]` extends `T => Boolean`, you can just use the set directly instead of having to write an explicit condition.

```
scala> "I like fish (but not herring)" exists blacklist
res1: Boolean = true

scala> "I like fish, especially salmon!" exists blacklist
res2: Boolean = false
```

(Note: be careful about the difference between strings, `"I am a string"` and characters: `'c'`.  A one-character string is a string, not a character.)